# How to cope with when exhaustive issue if i don't have nothing to return i case of else?

Tags: android, kotlin, case-when

I have a code that logically can have only 3 values. But the *when* assignment is on a **Int** variable type. What can i do, if i don't have a  RecyclerView.ViewHolder object to return if non of the "cases" in the *when* expression won't happen (a situation that can't be).
I can solve it with "ugly" solution that if 'else' so return of one of the RecyclerView.ViewHolder that i'm returning in the existing cases,  but i want to know if there is more elegant way to deal with this situation.
I have the following code:

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType)
     {
         DataTypesEnum.COUNTRY_ITEM.ordinal -> CountryDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
         DataTypesEnum.LEAGUE_ITEM.ordinal -> LeagueDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
         DataTypesEnum.GAME_ITEM.ordinal ->  GameDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
     }
}
```

the compiler says that :

> when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'else' branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [I] want to know if there is more elegant way to deal with this situation.

If you're *absolutely* sure that the `viewType` index will be in the right range, you can get the `enum` from the list. Then you'll just need to switch on that enum.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  return when (DataTypesEnum.values()[viewType])
  {
    DataTypesEnum.COUNTRY_ITEM -> CountryDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
    DataTypesEnum.LEAGUE_ITEM -> LeagueDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
    DataTypesEnum.GAME_ITEM ->  GameDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
  }
}
```

I agree with J. Hegg's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64948976/4951255) in that you should be cautious!

---

*Update 2020-11-23 with further context:*

> I'm just very curious how the line (DataTypesEnum.values()[viewType]) makes all the when return statement to be exhaustive and prevent from the compiler to complain on exhaustive issue?

In your initial example you switch on an `Int` type.

```kotlin
when (viewType) {
  // ...
}
```

Therefore, to make the complier happy with `viewTypes`, you either need to cover all possible values of `Int`, or include an `else` statement in the `when` block.

My suggestion maps the `Int` type to the corresponding `DataTypesEnum` before switching on it. That way, the `when` block only needs all `DataTypesEnum` options accounted for to be exhaustive.

`DataTypesEnum.values()` returns an `Array<DataTypesEnum>` of all of the `DataTypesEnum` in order which is very similar to using the [`#ordinal` values](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/ordinal.html) in your solution.

The next step is to get the value from the array, which I use the [index access operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed) `[ ]`.

```
DataTypesEnum.values()[viewType]
// is the same as
DataTypesEnum.values().get(viewType)
```

That should do the trick!

If you're not sure if `viewType` will fall into the right range, you might want to check the value [so you don't hit an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/get.html).

Hopefully that answers your question!

Comment: @Salvastore Testa, can you explain why the code you have wrote doesn't cause an error compilation? I understand the code but can't understand why it works? The compiler doesn't know that the enum can get only 3 values

Comment: @Eitanos30, I'm happy to try! Which part of what I wrote do you expect the compiler to complain about?

Comment: I must say i have checked what you wrote and it really works. But, I'm just very curious how the line (DataTypesEnum.values()[viewType]) makes all the *when* return statement to be exhaustive and prevent from the compiler to complain on exhaustive issue?

Comment: yes i understand and thanks again!!! But i curious how the compiler (not run time) knows that there are only 3 possible values for:DataTypesEnum.values()[viewType]? he doesn't actually checks how much enum values there are (only 3)..

Comment: The compiler knows about all possible cases for enum classes and sealed classes. See here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression

Comment: Of course! Feel free to mark the question as answered if you don't have any more questions.

Answer (score 3):

In your case it would be okay to throw an `InvalidArgumentException`. It should never happen that an unknown `ViewHolder` type can reach this point. If that happens, something went horribly wrong and you want to get notified about that.

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType)
     {
         DataTypesEnum.COUNTRY_ITEM.ordinal -> CountryDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
         DataTypesEnum.LEAGUE_ITEM.ordinal -> LeagueDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
         DataTypesEnum.GAME_ITEM.ordinal ->  GameDataItem.onCreateViewHolder(parent)
         else -> throw InvalidArgumentException("Invalid ViewHolder Type")
     }
}
```

If you want to avoid that warning you could make use of the [kotlin require operator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) and in that way exclude values that are not allowed. But if any value that is not allowed comes into that function it would also throw an exception.

Comment: I read the link you send. But i didn't understand how the require can serve me in order to prevent from *else*or should i use *require* in the *else* "case"

Comment: @Eitanos30 require, check, error are functions used for pre-checking, in this case is of no use.